# Javascript for measure browser performance to turn animations on or off

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, animation

I have a website with certain animations, CSS, animated gifs and "JS animations". On some mobile devices the animations are slow, so I want to detect that and turn the CSS animation off and use a static image for the gif animations instead.

The mobile devices browser do support CSS animations, but they're slow when it executes.

How can I measure the actual browser performance with a Javascript function so I can decide whether turn animations on or off? Any Javascript library maybe?

Comment: You could let the user decide to turn them off if their browser is locking up by providing a warning e.g. on sign-in

Comment: I can measure the performance of the JS function, but how to know if the gif animation is slow? or a CSS transition is slow? anyway to get the current framerate for a gif or css ransition via javascript to include it in the MyFnction() to test the performance?

Answer (score 1):

performance.now() is more accurate than using Date:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
your_function();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to your_function took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

And read the output in your console.

Comment: Just be aware that [performance.now might now be supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()), especially if it's on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to test the performance of a function is to run it. You could setup some kind of initial tests like the following:

```
var startTime = new Date();
possiblySlowFunction();
if (new Date() - startTime > maxAcceptableTime) {
    disableCSSAnimations();
}
```

The idea being, you give it a test run to determine how well it performs. In the case that it takes too long, do something to prevent using it again.

**Edit:** I'm making some mild assumptions with this answer. If this is a function that's been written by you, you'll first need to figure out what part of the function takes the longest. Then you can isolate that section into a test like what you see above and find a good number for determining if the function performs well enough.

Say, for example, you have an animation which requires you to alter a canvas on a per-pixel basis. You could setup a test which runs on a canvas 10x smaller than your real canvas and run the same algorithm on it. Now you have a benchmark for how long it takes on a smaller canvas so take that time and multiply it by 10. Is that an acceptable time for that animation? If not, disable the per-pixel canvas animations. This idea can be used for any kind of function, animation or otherwise.

Comment: So you're suggesting locking up the browser to see if something will lock up the browser to prevent it locking up the browser?

Comment: Not exactly. I made the assumption that this one function was either a collection of smaller, not as quick functions or a built-in function on a large data set. No one built-in function, on a reasonably sized data set, should take more than a few milliseconds on even the weakest of hardware. I'll update the answer to include that information.